# List of specific number from an uniform distribution, Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is a code that goes over numbers from a given uniform distribution y, and prints the number of values which are less than 1

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)

X = 0 # X number of y values < 1

for i in range(0,500):
  if y[i] < 1:
     X += 1
```

I would like to be able to repeat this process N times, then store each N values of these X. I tried nesting the for-loop structure inside another for-loop but I could not get it to work. As in

```
X = 0 # X number of y values < 1
N = 5

for k in range(N):
 for i in range(0,500):
  if y[i] < 1:
     X += 1
print(X)
```

Comment: Do you want 5 values for N at the end? (Will you resample `y` between each? inner loop)

Comment: Instead of maintaining an index why not `for value in y: if value < 1`? Or without a `for` loop: `X = sum(1 for i in y if i < 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will work, and you were very close. You want one outer loop to create the `N` samples of random of numbers `y` and one inner loop to count the number of `y`'s that are less than 1 for each sample. However every time you run the inner loop I think that you want to reset your counter `X` to 0, and to generate a new sample set of random numbers `y`.

```
for k in range(N):
 X=0
 y = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)
 for i in range(0,500):
  if y[i] < 1:
     X += 1
 print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop.

For one number, you can find the total like this:

```
sum([1 for i in y if i < 1])
```

If you want five numbers,

```
samples = []
for _ in range(N):
    y = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)
    samples.append(sum([1 for i in y if i < 1]))
```

You then have the five results in a list.

Comment: I just fixed that as you posted the comment

Comment: I should probably give up and deleted the answer now! Good spot.